# passing variable parameters in action class (Radio element), struts 2

Tags: java, struts2

I'm developing a Multiple Choice Quiz Application using `struts2`. The admin can decide how many questions the test will contain. So now my action class that'll receive the answers will have to receive multiple and unknown parameters.

Question are printed using iterator, Options are also randomized using a list named "randomNos" which contains random number.

```
<%int i=1; %>
<s:iterator var="i" value="quesList">
        <input type="hidden" value="<s:property value="QuesId"/>" name="quesId"/><%=i++ %>) <s:property value="Ques"/>
     <s:iterator var="j" value="randomNos">
      <s:if test="intValue() == 1"><input type="radio" name="ans" value="1"><s:property value="[1].Ans1"/>
    </s:if>

    <s:elseif test="intValue() == 2">input type="radio" name="ans" value="2"><s:property value="[1].Ans2"/>                                                     
    </s:elseif>

    <s:elseif test="intValue() == 3">
     <input type="radio" name="ans" value="3"><s:property value="[1].Ans3"/>
    </s:elseif>

    <s:else>
    <input type="radio" name="ans" value="4"><s:property value="[1].Ans4"/>
    </s:else>

    </s:iterator>
    </s:iterator>
```

Now to receive the parameter I tried "[Passing variable number of parameters from form in to action in struts 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900605/passing-variable-number-of-parameters-from-form-in-to-action-in-struts-2)"
But in my case I have Radio buttons, so now only one question's radio is selected as all buttons have the same name.

In my action I have

```
List<String> quesId;
List<String> ans;
```

and I iterate over both lists using iterators.

But the problem is only one option is selected of all questions. If I use a different "name" of the radio tags, I can't manage to put them in a list.

Comment: The name is either singular or plural, scriptlets is a bad code that is not formatted looks ugly.

Comment: Why are you using radio buttons if you want to get list of selected elements?

Comment: @AleksandrM - i'm developing a quiz system, it has multiple choice questions, so user has to pick 1 option from 4, so for this i used radio buttons. Now i want a list of selected radio buttons.

Comment: @RomanC - i have used scriptlet for a counter of questions, i couldn't find a way to do so using struts tag. btw i'm new to struts2.

Comment: @SumitGupta the iterator tag has a counter you don't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped "[Struts2 form to action fields mapping automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888329/struts2-form-to-action-fields-mapping-automatically)"
It says that implementing ParameterAware will get me a Map containing all request parameters.
A little modification in code and all works fine.